# Two spans side by side, one ellipsized

Tags: css, html

Say I have a single `div` containing a song title and the song's length (both `span`'s). I would like the title to appear in full if both `span`s are within the bounds of the container, but if the title's too long, I would like the title to be ellipsized, with the song length intact. Furthermore, the song length should always be to the right of the title - not floated to the rightmost corner of the container.

```
+-------------------+
+ a song 4:30       |
+-------------------+
+ another s... 4:30 |
+-------------------+
```

I have found a lot of examples similar to what I'm looking for - but in each case something seems to vary from what I need. Here's a close approximation to what I need - except in this JSFiddle the length is in the rightmost corner - whereas I need it to the right of the title: http://jsfiddle.net/gyaMf/

I don't necessarily know the width of "song length", but if it makes it easier, we can assume it's some preset width.

Comment: Not really sure what you want to achieve, but you can use `display:inline-block` to make the `span`s next to each other, [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gyaMf/3/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions everyone, but none of the solutions worked as needed. I was able to get a desirable solution, but not without jQuery:

```
var len = $title.outerWidth() + $length.outerWidth() + 14;
var available = $container.width() - $title.offset().left;

$container.toggleClass('too-long', len >= available);
```

I use jQuery to compute the total length of both spans; adding `too-long` CSS class to the container if there isn't enough space to fit both. ("14" is a somewhat arbitrary number that seems to work well given the size of text and how it's ellipsized when the container determines the contents overflow).

Without `too-long`, both spans render inline. With `too-long`:

```
.too-long {
    padding-right: 3.5em;
}

.too-long .length {
    position: absolute;
    right: 2em;
}
```

Because the container has `position: relative`, this results in the desired effect - length flows with title, but "sticks" to the right edge of the container when there's no longer any available space. The downside of this is that every time title or length change, `too-long` must be re-evaluated, but I already do various other CSS adjustments when that happens, so it's not that much added work.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this using a combination of the `:after` pseudo element and `attr` content.

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ksVPh/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="song">
<span len="4:31" class="title">This is the song</span>
</div>

<div class="song">
<span len="4:31" class="title">This is the</span>
</div>

<div class="song">
<span len="4:31" class="title">This</span>
</div>

<div class="song">
<span len="4:31" class="title">This is the song titlee </span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.song {
    font-size: 14px;
    width:160px;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.title {
    white-space: nowrap;
    width:100px;
    display:block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
.title:after {
    content:attr(len);
    padding-left:5px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use flexbox:
http://jsbin.com/rojam/3

```
container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row
  flex-wrap: nowarp;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: baseline;
  align-content: center;
}

span.name {
  white-space: nowrap;                  
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

span.len {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```